# How to tell when Android is shutting down?

Tags: android, android-source, shutdown, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

How can I tell when Android is shutting down?

I can put the functionality into a C++ daemon which is already running as root, or into an unprivileged Java app.

Can I distinguish shutting down from rebooting?  (I only care about shutting down, and must not get a false-positive when rebooting.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a broadcast Receiver:

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (ACTION_SHUTDOWN.equals(intent.getAction()) || QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // Do something..
    }
}
```

Apply an intent filter to your manifest declared broadcast receiver to listen to two actions:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger your c service in initrc:

1. trigger by property:

   on property:sys.shutdown.requested=*
   stop cnss-daemon
2. trigger by [shutdown critical](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/master/init/README.md)

> `shutdown <shutdown_behavior>`
>   Set shutdown behavior of the service process. When this is not specified,
>     the service is killed during shutdown process by using SIGTERM and SIGKILL.
>     The service with shutdown_behavior of "critical" is not killed during shutdown
>     until shutdown times out. When shutdown times out, even services tagged with
>     "shutdown critical" will be killed. When the service tagged with "shutdown critical"
>     is not running when shut down starts, it will be started.